# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'logger') after upgrade to Umbraco 10

Tags: umbraco, .net-6.0

I've upgraded our project from Umbraco 9 to Umbraco 10.
On start I see this exception: "**Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'logger')"**

It goes away if I remove this code from Program.cs/ CreateHostBuilder

```
.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
        loggerConfiguration
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
         .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(new TelemetryConfiguration { InstrumentationKey = hostingContext.Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"]
}, TelemetryConverter.Traces));
```

Could you please help me to figure out how to modify this code properly so that Umbraco 10 is happy :)

Stacktrace:

```
    Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Logging.RegisteredReloadableLogger..ctor(ReloadableLogger logger)
Umbraco.Extensions.ServiceCollectionExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<AddLogger>b__0(IServiceProvider sp)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService<T>(IServiceProvider provider)
Umbraco.Extensions.ServiceCollectionExtensions+<>c.<AddLogger>b__1_2(IServiceProvider sp)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService<T>(IServiceProvider provider)
Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.ModelsBuilder.RefreshingRazorViewEngine..ctor(Func<IRazorViewEngine> defaultRazorViewEngineFactory, InMemoryModelFactory inMemoryModelFactory)
Umbraco.Extensions.UmbracoBuilderDependencyInjectionExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<AddInMemoryModelsRazorEngine>b__0(IServiceProvider s)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService<T>(IServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllerRoute(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, string name, string pattern, object defaults, object constraints, object dataTokens)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapAreaControllerRoute(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, string name, string areaName, string pattern, object defaults, object constraints, object dataTokens)
Umbraco.Extensions.EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapUmbracoRoute(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, Type controllerType, string rootSegment, string areaName, string prefixPathSegment, string defaultAction, bool includeControllerNameInRoute, object constraints)
Umbraco.Cms.Web.BackOffice.Routing.BackOfficeAreaRoutes.MapMinimalBackOffice(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
Umbraco.Cms.Web.BackOffice.Routing.BackOfficeAreaRoutes.CreateRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
Umbraco.Extensions.UmbracoApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseBackOfficeEndpoints(IUmbracoEndpointBuilderContext app)
JemOgFix.Webshop.Startup+<>c.<Configure>b__4_2(IUmbracoEndpointBuilderContext u) in Startup.cs
+
                    u.UseBackOfficeEndpoints();
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action<IEndpointRouteBuilder> configure)
Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.ApplicationBuilder.UmbracoApplicationBuilder.WithEndpoints(Action<IUmbracoEndpointBuilderContext> configureUmbraco)
JemOgFix.Webshop.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in Startup.cs
+
            app.UseUmbraco()
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object target, ref Span<object> arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor, bool wrapExceptions)
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsightsStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
JemOgFix.Webshop.Program.Main(string[] args) in Program.cs
+
            => CreateHostBuilder(args)
```